# Question about p-value for one-sided hypothesis testing

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Is it true that the p-value is symmetric?

Let's say for a null hypothesis $H_{0}$: p = 0.75. Given that the z-score test statistics equals 1.44. Using the R command, I found out that

```
pnorm(1.44, lower=F) 
## [1] 0.0749337
```

I want to test $H_{\alpha}: p > 0.75$. I concluded that p-value is equal to 0.0749337 because by definition, assume H0 is true, then the p-value is the probability that the test statistic z takes a value (in support of $H_{\alpha}$) as or more extreme than the one we observed. For a two-sided hypothesis testing, $H_{0}: p \neq 0.75$, the p-value would be 2*0.0749337.

Now, my quesiton is: can I claim that the p-value for $H_{\alpha}: p < 0.75$ is also 0.0749337?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems you may be dividing the _one_-sided P-value by 2, which would not be correct. See my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing an approximate normal test of $H_0: p = 3/4$ vs $H_a: p \ne 3/4,$ rejecting when $|Z_{\text{obs}}| > 1.96,$ where
$$Z_{\text{obs}} = \frac{\hat p = 3/4}{\sqrt{\frac{(3/4)[1-(3/4)]}{n}}},$$
then the two-sided P-value is $P(|Z| > Z_{\text{obs}}),$ where $Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$

So if $Z_{\text{obs}} = 1.44,$ then the P-value is $P(Z \le -1.44) + P(Z\ge 1.44) = 2P(Z \ge 1.44) \approx 0.15.$

However, if you do an *exact* 2-sided binomial test, then the null distribution of
the number $X$ of successes is $\mathsf{Binom(n, 3/4)},$ which is not a
symmetrical distribution. Opinions vary how to find the P-value in that case. Some authors and software packages interpret "more extreme" than $X_{\text{obs}}$ to mean farther in absolute value from the mean $np_0 = n(3/4)$
than $X_{\text{obs}}$ in either direction. Then finding the P-value may involve
adding two somewhat different tail probabilities, and I suppose this would not match your idea of 'symmetry'. Some simply double the probability from the 'observed tail`.

*Note:* I can't illustrate the exact binomial test for your case, because you have
not given the values of $X_{\text{obs}}$ and $n.$ However, since you have R,
you can look at the help screen at `? binom.test` where the example shows
the same null and alternative hypotheses as yours with $X = 682$ and $n = 925.$
The P-value for the exact binomial test is given as `0.3825`. With the
approximate normal test, I obtain a P-value $\approx 2(.186) = 0.372.$

Comment: Hello, if I am doing an approximate normal test, then I can conclude that the p-value for  $H\alpha : p < 0.75$ is also 0.0749337. Right?

Comment: No. If you have $\hat p > .75$ and $Z = 1.44,$ then P-value for testing $H_0: p \ge .75$ vs. $H_a < .75$ is huge: 0.9250663. // With $\hat p > .75$ you certainly have _no_ evidence the $H_a$ is true.